# The video loop is multipling itself more than one time every time it ends

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

This question is using Aframe .
I have the videosphere on loop manually with addEventListener on ("end"). 
Code works fine until I look at the console. It gives me strange logs.

```
myvideo = document.querySelector("#videoSphere");

var aEntranceScene1 = document.querySelectorAll("#playButton1");
for (var i = 0; i < aEntranceScene1.length; i++) {
aEntranceScene1[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    Scene1();
});
};

function Scene1(){
myvideo.setAttribute("src", "video/AEntranceScene1.mp4");
    myvideo.currentTime = 0;
    myvideo.play();
    console.log("playing AEntranceScene1");
    Hotspots();

myvideo.addEventListener("ended", function () {
    console.log("AEntranceScene1 ended");
Scene1();
    });
};

function Hotspots() {
sceneIndex = 1;
document.querySelector("#DButton").emit("disappear");

setTimeout(function () {
    if (sceneIndex == 1 && !myvideo.paused) {
        document.querySelector("#DButton").emit("move-start");
    }
}, 3000);
};
```

When the video plays first time. It displays the log "playing 
AEntranceScene1 and when it ended, log displays "AEntranceScene1 ended" 1 time as expected.this (Attached the photo0) played 1 time [image: this (Attached the photo0) played 1 time]

But then when the video play again.  It displays the log "playing 
AEntranceScene1" several times, not only add one. When it ended, log also displays several times of "AEntranceScene1 ended" this (Attached the photo1) played 2 time
[image: this (Attached the photo1) played 2 time]

This would get worst as more loop completed.This (Attached the photo2) played 3 times only
[[image: This (Attached the photo2) played 3 times only]

[image]

Can you explain to me whats happening here? and any fix to my code?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself.

Its caused by putting `autoplay` in the `<a-assets>`,
once i deleted `autoplay`, it works fine